# How to send axios reques in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to send axios request to my backend but I'm stuck in it.

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    
        const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
        console.log('kk');
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
    
};
```

when it tries to post request through axios it gives following error.[image: error]

although I haved tried this in React JS and it's working perfectly.
please help me to solve this in react native

Answer (score 1):

Per the [React Native Networking Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network), React Native supports the [`fetch` web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for sending requests.  I advise you use `fetch` instead of `axios` as it has all of the same features without any added bloat and overhead.  Here is a port of your code to use `fetch`:

```js
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
   const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/`, {
      method: "POST", // this signnifies POST request type
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }), // still including the body
      headers: {
         // apply the headers
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
   });

   const data = await res.json(); // parses the body as a json object

   console.log("kk");

   dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
   });

   dispatch(load_user());
};
```

Comment: @Ruma Then add a try-catch around the request code then log out the error.

Comment: I've tried, in that case  catch block is running. even before console.log() line

Comment: @Ruma Yes, that means your request is failing. Have you setup CORS?

Comment: Yes I have setup cores, and on react js project these are working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```js
// define axios request

import axios from 'axios';

const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://url.com/api/v1',
  timeout: 20000,
});

request.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    // config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    config.headers.Accept = 'Application/json';
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    //return Promise.reject(error);
    console.log("interceptors.request: ", error);
    return false;
  },
);

request.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response && response.data) {
      return response.data;
    }

    return response;
  },
  error => {
    console.log('Response error: ', error);
    //throw error;
    return false;
  },
);

export default request;
```

Usage:

```js
import request from '../';

export const getAPI = () => {
  return request({
    url: '/getData',
    method: 'GET',
    // ...
  });
};
```

```js
getAPI().then(response => {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more. where to write this code and how to to use this in my code